# documentation for REST API project

Tags: python, django, rest

i want to make documentation of my DJANGO REST framework project like twitter documentation
[[https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1]](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1%5d)

how can i do it?

is there any better way to implement documentation rather then this one?

Answer (score 1):

DRF provides its own description for what you are asking in [documenting your api](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api) section. Choose the one that suits you better.